# Sharepoint webpart using yoeman scafollding....not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-dev-pnp

Tried developing the hello web part from yo man scaffolding. Everything works except when tried to package-solution and install it on office 365 site... I am getting...You can't add this app here. "Supported languages are not specified".

I am not sure what is that I am missing. Locale.js is added ofcourse.
It works fine when used with Workbench.aspx from my own site.

Thanks in advance.

-Satyen

Comment: Did you stop `gulp serve` before trying to run `gulp package-solution`? Also, make sure you are in `/hello-world/` and not in `/hello-world/config/` when running `gulp package-solution`

Comment: Thanks...I did all that. When I went to a sub site surprisingly it did work. Honestly, I am not sure how it started working at this time. One thing I remember I changed the version number of the part and waited 10 minutes after I dropped in App Catalog.